# как конвертировать строку в нецелое число

Tags: python, файлы, числа

```
f = open('1.txt')
a = []
for n in range(5):
  x = int(f.readline())
  a.append(x)
```

файл состоит из нецелых чисел : `52.1` , `23.6` и тд

```
x = int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '49.30\n'
```

появляется такая ошибка, как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(f.readline())
```

`int` - это целые числа, а числа с плавающей точкой это `float`:

```
x = float(f.readline())
```